# How do I import a dll file to JetBrains Rider IDE?

Tags: c#, dll, jetbrains-ide, rider

I'm trying to open a .dll assembly in JetBrains Rider 2023.2.3 at the location indicated by the red arrow, but I can't open the corresponding code. Anyone with experience in JetBrains Rider 2023.2.3 help me?

I'm trying to open an extension file .dll, but I don't know how to do that.

[image]

Comment: the dll is compiled binary which you can't open just as is. If the library is in .net, you can try to use some disassembler tools like `ildasm` or `ilspy`, but you will see not the same code as initial one. All syntax sugar that is provided by .net will be lost as well as in general code will look more "low level"ed than you may expect, but it can give you some understanding what happens inside the dll

Comment: [This?](https://github.com/chen0040/cs-expert-system-shell)

Comment: @stuartd : You need net core 1.0 installed to run.  It may be better OP recompiles the project to same version of Net/Core that he is using.

Comment: @jdweng agreed just thought that looked like the source

Answer (score 0):

Assemblies referenced by your project(s) are already compiled, so you shouldn't expect navigating its source code just like your own.

However, Rider does allow you decompile the assemblies if you really need that, via its "Assembly Explorer" view. You can learn more from the official documentation,

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Exploring_Assemblies.html